# Use javascript variable in first part of object name

Tags: javascript, variables, object

The code breaks on the first [. The uniqueid is a variable.

```
function() {            
    ['fg'+uniqueid].setPagination();
}
```

I know the [] method can be used for variables in object names, but apparently not when the variable is the first in line? Anyone an idea what's the correct method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation), you need the parent object, even if it's `window`, like this:

```
window['fg'+uniqueid].setPagination();
```

Or, if it's something else:

```
myObject['fg'+uniqueid].setPagination();
```

Or relatively:

```
this['fg'+uniqueid].setPagination();
```

Comment: Great, the window method works great! The other two methods don't work in my code. Thanks for the great and quick help!